# Cannot construct the infinite type - implementing tail-recursive factorial calculator

Tags: haskell, recursion, tail-recursion, factorial

I am trying to implement a tail recursive version of factorial:

```
let{factorial 0 n = n; factorial x n =  factorial (x-1, n * x)}
```

I get this:

```
<interactive>:1:41:
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t1 = t1 -> t1
In the return type of a call of `factorial'
In the expression: factorial (x - 1, n * x)
In an equation for `factorial':
    factorial x n = factorial (x - 1, n * x)

<interactive>:1:52:
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t0 = (t0, t1)
In the first argument of `(-)', namely `x'
In the expression: x - 1
In the first argument of `factorial', namely `(x - 1, n * x)'

<interactive>:1:61:
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t1 = (t0, t1)
In the second argument of `(*)', namely `x'
In the expression: n * x
In the first argument of `factorial', namely `(x - 1, n * x)'
```

How am i constructing an infinite type here? (using GHCi 7.0.1)

Comment: If you give your definition type signatures, the error messages are usually easier to understand. You'd have gotten something along the lines of ``Couldn't match expected type `Integer' with actual type `(t0, t1)'`` then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not a strong Haskell programmer, but I think you want to rewrite

```
factorial x n =  factorial (x-1, n * x)
```

as

```
factorial x n =  factorial (x-1) (n * x)
```

Since `(x-1, n * x)` is a pair type, which isn't what you want.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ofcourse! Despite knowing about pairs, I'll blame my habit of passing args to a function, er.. 'non-functional programming way'? :)